# Filters on DisplayObject Not working

Tags: html, blur, haxe, dropshadow, openfl

I'm trying to add DropShadowFilter / BlurFilter / GlowFilter to a simple Sprite on stage.
If i target flash, it looks and behaves fine. When i target HTML5, i see nothing.

The wiki says "Available on all platforms" (link).
Am i doing something wrong?

I'm importing
import openfl.filters.BlurFilter;
import openfl.display.Sprite;

Here is the code im using:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
s.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
s.graphics.endFill();
var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(40, 40, 1);
s.filters = [blur];
addChild(s);
```

HTML5 PRINTSCREEN:
[image]

FLASH PRINTSCREEN:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now there is little to no support for filters on any target but Flash.

The good news is that we are working on implementing custom shaders and filters for OpenFL `next` on every target that uses OpenGL. Here is the PR and discussion https://github.com/openfl/openfl/pull/697

[image: html5 webgl]

I would guess that some filters could be implemented via software for HTML5 canvas, but I'm not focusing on that in that PR.

Answer (score 0):

As far as im aware filters are not supported in legacy or next. Ive never seen them working anyway. I presume eventually they will be supported in next.

Comment: Its worth noting that im not sure about that. I havent even seen them work, but its possible im doing something wrong also.